# Nano Pi Neo Plus2 GPIO poweroff

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, device-tree

I'm trying to make use of gpio-poweroff procedure. I'm trying to understand the consequences of the approach I've used.

Here's what I did

1) Added

```
power_ctrl: power_ctrl {
   compatible = "gpio-poweroff";
   gpios = <&pio 6 11 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
    force;
};
```

to [arch/arm64/boot/dts/allwinner/sun50i-h5-nanopi-neo-plus2.dts](https://github.com/friendlyarm/linux/blob/sunxi-4.x.y/arch/arm64/boot/dts/allwinner/sun50i-h5-nanopi-neo-plus2.dts#L86)

2) Recompiled the device tree blob and put it where it belongs

The gpio-poweroff's code got probed but failed due to `pm_poweroff_handler` being set to something. So I figured it out that it's set to `psci_sys_poweroff` in [drivers/firmware/psci.c](https://github.com/friendlyarm/linux/blob/sunxi-4.x.y/drivers/firmware/psci.c#L518).

3) I commented this line out

4) Rebooted with a new kernel and issued `poweroff` on command line

5) The GPIO was driven high as expected

6) The board is switched off by external circuitry

I'm very eager to know if this is an OK thing to do on an embedded system? It seems like I do something nasty. The only reasonable approach that comes to mind is to use some kind of chain of callbacks with GPIO poweroff handler's priority set to low. So that I could toggle GPIO and then use the PSCI logic to properly shutdown. But the [RFC](https://lists.gt.net/linux/kernel/2046418) with this approach got rejected and nobody seems to be stepping in.

Another solution is to make an ugly hack in gpio-poweroff.c and save the old callback to a variable and call it after gpio toggled.

So what do you guys think?

Comment: The things that really matter are if you synced and safed your filesystems and storage media before what amounts to an intentional brownout crash, and if your actual power switch circuit obeys all electrical rules - *especially* the common one applicable to many I/O pins which prohibites the presence of any signal voltage when the corresponding power supply is missing.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Thanks for your comment. The thing is I'm not that sure what this PSCI logic does. Our powerswitch just waits for gpio-poweroff to do its thing on a pin and then powers off Linux board completely. Could you elaborate a bit on "intentional brownout crash"?

Comment: Powering off the board with an external switch is an "intentional brownout crash".  My point was that how that is done is probably not the main concern.  Rather the concern is that you first get the system and particularly its storage into a state where that is safe.  And then that you need to insure that no electrical specifications are violated, for example by having voltages on I/O pins when your computer is not powered, something typically prohibited for on-board interfaces, but against which external interfaces are sometimes armored.  In other words, examine the circuit vs data sheets.

Comment: Thank you for making these issues more clear. So the only matter left is whether there is a cleaner solution for the powering off sequence rather that patching the kernel code.